# How do I load test a RabbitMQ server (Either using JMeter, python or any other tool..)?

Tags: load, jmeter, rabbitmq, load-testing, amqp

I have been given access to a RabbitMQ server to do a load test on it. I'm completely new to servers and AMQ protocol. I've been researching online to see what are some different methods. So far I'm investigating two methods.

1. JMeter; I have found this project: https://github.com/jlavallee/JMeter-Rabbit-AMQP#build-dependencies . It gives me a jar file which I can create JMeter AMQP consumer and publisher, but I have no idea what to put in the fields. (virtual host vs host - dunno my ports -..)
   [image]
2. Python; using Pika.
   I have a simple sender script which connects from my client to my server and sends a 'hello world' text to the server. Also wrote a receiver script to receive those 'hello world's. Is this a determination of load if I open multiple terminals and run my sender script 10 instances at the same time?

Again, I'm asking all these because I'm new to servers, cloud, load testing and Jmeter. It's just a task I have to do.

Thanks for any answer you can give me to clarify things a bit for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can use rabbitmq's Java Client Tools:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html

It comes with a PerfTest:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-tools.html

You can run it using this command:

```
./runjava.sh com.rabbitmq.examples.PerfTest \
-h amqp://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<vhost> \
-x <number_of_producers> \
-y <number_of_consumers> \
-s <message_size> \
-C <total_number_of_message> \
-u <queue_name>
```

There are other flags you can use too if you look at the documentation or the source you can see what they are.

**Update/Shameless Plug**
I wrote a web app that pulls these tools into one place https://github.com/johnlonganecker/rabbitmq-performance-app
[image]

Comment: It looks like `PerfTest.java` has moved to the `com.rabbitmq.perf` package now. You might want to update your answer.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I will update in when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have jar with you, place it under jmeter/lib/ext folder. Now open Jmeter and prepare a test plan.

**Step 1:** To click test plan, right click Test Plan and go to  Add->Thread(Users)->Thread Group. Give a name to Thread Group:

[image]

**Step 2:** Then right click your group and go to Add->Sampler->AMQP Publisher:

[image]

**Give Host as "localhost", Port as "5672", Username and Password as "guest/guest".**

**Also select/de-select features like "durable","persistence" etc as per your exchange setup.**

**Step 3:** Then right click your group and go to Add->Listener->Graph Results:

[image]

**Step 4:** Now save the test plan and execute.

[image]

For more detailed setup, you can refer to my blog at:

http://jatinanejablog.blogspot.in/2016/06/configure-jmeter-to-load-test-rabbit-mq.html

Answer (score 0):

I have an issue. Tried to build an AMQP publish request to a AZURE Service Bus server. I understand that this plugin may work for other AMQP messages not only Rabbit.

But i keep getting this error like is not even making a connection:

> 024-01-30 11:16:20,937 INFO c.z.j.p.a.AMQPSampler: RabbitMQ
> ConnectionFactory using:   virtual host: /     host: servicebus.net
> port: 5672     username: name      password: password      timeout: 1000
> heartbeat: 60 in
> com.zeroclue.jmeter.protocol.amqp.AMQPPublisher@229b1d71 2024-01-30
> 11:16:21,021 WARN c.z.j.p.a.AMQPPublisher: null
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
> com.zeroclue.jmeter.protocol.amqp.AMQPPublisher.sample(AMQPPublisher.java:109)
> [jmeter-amqp-plugin-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]  at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]     at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]     at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]     at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> [?:1.8.0_401]